# Why is the vertex sequence in Diestel's Lemma 1.5.5. defined the way it is?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Sorry if the title is a bit cryptic, but I do not know how else put my question to words. So [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WezkU.png) when we show that any two vertices of a normal tree are separated by the set $\lceil{x}\rceil \bigcap \lceil{y}\rceil$ why can we not have that $t_{i-1} < t_i > t_{i+1}$ for any i? This seems somewhat reasonable if we note that a tree does not have any cycles, so we cannot first go up and then down a level. But I cannot understand the reasoning presented in the page.

Given this, the ordering $x = t_i > \dots > t_k < \dots < t_n = y$, does also make sense if we imagine it as either moving first downwards some number of vertices, and the moving upwards, or just taking the negation of the impossible ordering and throwing away the equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $t_{i-1}<t_i>t_{i+1}$. Then both $t_{i-1}$ and $t_{i+1}$ are below $t_i$ in the tree $T$, so they both lie on the path through $T$ from the root to $t_i$. This implies that they are comparable in $T$: either $t_{i-1}<t_{i+1}$, $t_{i-1}=t_{i+1}$, or $t_{i+1}<t_{i-1}$ in the tree-order of $T$. And in that case the sequence $t_1,\ldots,t_{i-1},t_{i+1},\ldots,t_n$ is a sequence of vertices in $P\cap T$ such that $t_1=x$, $t_n=y$, and consecutive terms are comparable in the tree-order of $T$ — and it’s shorter than the minimal such sequences. This is impossible, so the minimal sequence cannot contain such an up-down triple.

Intuitively, a minimal sequence of that kind cannot go up a branch and then back down, because we can always remove the up-down detour to get a shorter sequence of that kind.