# Understanding the proof of Diestel's Lemma 1.5.5 (i) concerning a normal tree T in a graph G and comparability of nodes w.r.t. the tree-order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I have problems understanding the minimal vertex sequence $x = t_1 > \dots > t_k < \dots < t_n = y$ used in the proof of Diestel's Lemma 1.5.5 (i) (see [Link](https://www.diestel-graph-theory.com/GrTh5_corrections.pdf)).

To quote its definition:

> Let $T$ be a normal tree in a graph $G$ and $x$,$y$ any two vertices $x$,$y \in T$ that are incomparable in its tree. Let $P$ be any $x$-$y$ path in $G$. Let $t_1, ..., t_n$ be a minimal sequence of vertices in $P \cap T$ such that $t_1 = x$ and $t_n = y$ and $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ are comparable in the tree-order of $T$ for all $i$.

It then goes on to show that this implies $$x = t_1 > \dots > t_k < \dots < t_n = y$$ I do very well understand why $t_{i-1} < t_i > t_{i+1}$ is not possible (see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808366/why-is-the-vertex-sequence-in-diestels-lemma-1-5-5-defined-the-way-it-is) question) as comparability of $t_{i-1}$ and $t_{i+1}$ follows by both being an elment of $rTt_i$ and hence, the sequence would violate minimality ($t_i$ could be removed).

However, lets assume $t_{i-1} > t_i > t_{i+1}$. Wouldn't $t_{i-1} > t_{i+1}$ follow from transitivity? Or from a graph theoretic argument: As $t_i$ is an element of the up-closure of $t_{i+1}$ it follows that $t_{i+1} \in rTt_i$ and because $t_i \ne t_{i+1}$, $t_i$ lies at a higher level in $T$. Now, $t_{i-1}$ is in the up-closure of $t_i$, hence $t_i \in rTt_{i-1}$ (and again $t_{i-1} \ne t_i$). But because $T$ is a tree, any two vertices of $T$ are linked by a unique path in $T$ (otherwise $T$ would include a cylce). Hence, $rTt_i \subset rTt_{i-1}$ as both paths include a subpath from $r$ to $t_i$ and $t_i \ne t_{i-1}$. But this implies that $t_{i+1} \in rTt_{i-1}$ as well and hence, $t_{i+1}$ and $t_{i-1}$ are again comparable. With this reasoning, the minimal vertex sequence looks as follows: $x = t_1 >  t_2 < t_3 = y$.

So I am wondering, where my reasoning went wrong, and what parts of the tree-order concept I have still not understood.

EDIT: From my understanding now, for the proof in Diestel specifying the $k$ is not necessary. Therefore, I think it was just not bothered to show that $k=2$. But I am still very open to an answer proofing me wrong or affirming my $k=2$ argument.

Comment: Why you conclude that there is $t_2$ as "father" of the two nodes? if they are on far away branches, the path from the first to the second can be very very long (maybe up to the root)...

Comment: By definition $t_1$ and $t_3$ are incomparable. Therefore, if $t_1 < t_2 > t_3$ it follows that $t_1$ and $t_3$ are comparable, which is a contradiction. I give an argument if  $t_{i-1} > t_{i} > t_{i+1}$ (or $t_{i-1} < t_i < t_{i+1}$) the nodes $t_{i-1}$ and $t_{i+1}$ would also be comparable, which would violate the sequence being minimal as we could remove $t_i$ and still satisfy the definition of the vertex sequence. Therefore, the only option left is $t_1 > t_2 < t_3$. However, in my argument I must have some mistake as it contradicts Diestel's result on how the sequence looks.

Comment: But the issue is that starting with $x=t_1$ we must have $t_1 > t_2$ and not the other way... And the same for $t_{n-1} < t_n=y$.

Comment: For me it is clear that $t_1 > t_2$ and $t_{n-1} < t_n$, but why does $t_{i-1} > t_i > t_{i+1}$ not imply $t_{i-1} > t_{i+1}$ or does it? Reading the proof of Lemma 1.5.5 (i) I realize, specifying the form of the sequence further is not necessary for the proof.

Comment: It does, but a certain point, being the path finite, we arrive at $t_k$ such that we have also $t_k < t_{k+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! My confusion is from the fact that Diestel states the sequence must be minimal. Hence, every element should be removed which is not necessary. I argue that therefore $k=2$ because otherwise it wouldn't be minimal w.r.t. the number of vertices in the sequence, resulting in $x = t_1 > t_2 < t_3 = y$. (If $t_{i-1} > t_i > t_{i+1}$ I just remove $t_i$ from the sequence yielding a smaller sequence - and same for $t_{i-1} < t_i < t_{i+1}$ - until I eventually end up at a sequence of length three).